# Where can I find some websites with VB.NET tutorials?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am looking for a website similar to W3Schools that teaches the basics for VB.NET 2008.

If none exist I would just like some good tutorials to get me started. I did some basic VB.NET a couple of years ago but I need to refresh myself, any ideas?

Comment: @Rich B/Luke: should the title be "Where can I find some websites with VB.NET tutorials?". That's how I understood it.

Comment: @Martin: Sure. Looks good to me.

Comment: Yeh maybe I cant remember what I wrote, sorry very tired. Zzzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has some really good screencasts: http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos.aspx

More videos here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb466226.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can find visual basic tutorials in MSDN: go to the [Visual Basic Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vbasic/default.aspx) for a start.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be as nicely formatted as w3schools, but MSDN is probably the best place for you.  They have pretty good documentation from what I've seen, but I don't work in VB too much.  Here's the link, though.  This should be roughly what you're looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[101 Samples for Visual Basic 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms789075.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[learnvisualstudio.net](http://learnvisualstudio.net)  it isn't free, but they have great video tutorials

Answer (score -1):

I know of this one for VB.NET 2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb964686.aspx

You will need to accept the license, and then you will download a zip file with various samples for VB.NET 2008.