# VB.NET Online Tutorials

Tags: .net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find some websites with VB.NET tutorials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579700/where-can-i-find-some-websites-with-vb-net-tutorials)

Are there any good online vb.net tutorials. I am taking a class on vb.net and want to find a really good tutorial. i am trying to find some tutorials on the language itself instead of form design or asp.net. I need to know the language.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to know C# and .NET pretty well (based on your profile.) I was in the same situation a couple of years back (needing to pick up .NET for a project) [This C#/VB.NET comparison page](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html) was my most useful resource by far.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of tutorials online, and I can't really suggest one over another, but I have found these conversion tools invaluable when trying to figure out how to do soemthing in VB.NET:

- http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/
- http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: +1 I used those resource extensively as well. Only caveat to mention is that the converters are not and cannot be 100% effective. There are features in the languages that simply cannot be converted auto-magically.